# Redirecting stdout and stderr when embedding libPython

Tags: python, ios

I have embedded libPython.a in a iOS app and I am running a script using `PyRun_SimpleFileEx`:

```
    Py_SetPythonHome((char *)[resourcePath UTF8String]);

    Py_Initialize();

    const char* argv[] = {
       …
       ">/dev/null"
    };
    PySys_SetArgv(sizeof(argv)/sizeof(char*), (char**)argv);

    PyEval_InitThreads();

    const char* prog = ...;

    FILE* fd = fopen(prog, "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        ret = 1;
    } else {
        ret = PyRun_SimpleFileEx(fd, prog, 1);
        if (ret != 0)
            NSLog(@"Application quit abnormally!");
    }

    Py_Finalize();
```

Everything works fine, but I haven't found a way to redirect stdout/stderr so that I get no logging on the iOS console.

I tried by adding ">/dev/null" as an additional argument to the script, but it obviously does not work since there is no shell.

How can I redirect stdout/stderr in such a scenario? Or alternatively, there is a way to "intercept" all Python output calls? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using libpython in this manner, the `stdout` and `stderr` are the ones of the process that calls `PyRun_SimpleFileEx`. You could try

```
freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
```

If you want to restore them after the script has run, you should look into `dup` to get the original values first and then restore them.